# What is the quickest way to convert scalar property to item list in MSBUILD

Tags: msbuild

What is the most terse way to convert $(Property) to @(ItemList) in MSBUILD file?

Answer (score 4):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <SomeItem Include="$(Property)"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that one could use $(Property) when item array is expected. So there no need for conversion.